# Group by predefined date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

How can I count the number of occurence in a table during a predefined period stored in an other table ?

I have 2 tables :

```
table1
+------------+---------+---------+
| Period     | value 1 | value 2 |
+------------+---------+---------+
| 2021-01-01 | 1234    | 45678   |
| 2021-02-01 | 345     | 3456    |
| 2021-03-01 | 34567   | 45678   |
+------------+---------+---------+

table 2
+------------+---------+
| Date       | boolean |
+------------+---------+
| 2021-01-03 | 1       |
| 2021-01-06 | 0       |
| 2021-02-05 | 1       |
| 2021-02-13 | 1       |
| 2021-03-06 | 1       |
+------------+---------+
```

And I want the following result

```
+------------+---------+---------+-------|
| Period     | value 1 | value 2 | count |
+------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2021-01-01 | 1234    | 45678   | 1     |
| 2021-02-01 | 345     | 3456    | 2     |
| 2021-03-01 | 34567   | 45678   | 1     |
+------------+---------+---------+-------+
```

I tried things like

```
SELECT t1.*, SUM(t2.boolean) as count
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
WHERE t2.Date BETWEEN t1.period AND DATEADD(month, 1, t1.period)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close. To define your tables' relationships in your `FROM` clause you don't want a `WHERE` clause, you want an `ON` clause:

```
SELECT t1.*, SUM(t2.boolean) as count
FROM table1 t1
   LEFT JOIN table2 t2
       ON t2.Date BETWEEN t1.period AND DATEADD(month, 1, t1.period)
```

Furthermore, because you are aggregating with a `SUM()` in your SELECT you will need to provide a `GROUP BY` to tell the database which columns to group on (every column that isn't being aggregated with a function like `SUM()`):

```
SELECT t1.*, SUM(t2.boolean) as count
FROM table1 t1
   LEFT JOIN table2 t2
       ON t2.Date BETWEEN t1.period AND DATEADD(month, 1, t1.period)
GROUP BY t1.period, t1.value1, t1.value2
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you want all columns from the first table, I would recommend a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       (SELECT SUM(t2.boolean) as count
        FROM table2 t2
        WHERE t2.Date BETWEEN t1.period AND DATEADD(month, 1, t1.period)
       ) as count
FROM table1 t1;
```

Depending on the nature of the data and the indexes, this might be faster as well -- avoiding the outer aggregation is often a win.